# flycheck - elpy - flake8 - ein and .ipynb files

Tags: python, flycheck, elpy, ein, jupyter

I have set up Emacs (on Mac Catalina) with Elpy to handle Python.
I also managed to get Jupyter notebooks (`.ipynb` files) working with Elpy via Ein. 
Both `.py` and `.ipynb` compile and use Flycheck correctly.

I have problems with `.ipynb` notebooks:

I find that Flycheck does not work properly because of the `In [ ]:`

I found `flake8_nb` (and not 'flake8`) works fine with them from the command line:

```
flake8_nb name.ipynb
```

My question now is:
How can I set up Emacs/elpy to use `flake8` with `py` files and `flake8_nb` with `.ipynb`?

From what I have understood, Elpy calls flake8 through `python-flake8` but I cannot find an option to make it use flake8_nb with `.ipynb` files.

Can you please help me?

This is my `.emacs` Python part:

```lisp
    (use-package elpy
      :ensure t
      :init
      (elpy-enable))

    (when(require 'ein)
    (setq ein:use-auto-complete-superpack t))

    (when (require 'flycheck nil t)
      (setq elpy-modules (delq 'elpy-module-flymake elpy-modules))
      (add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode))

    (add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)

    (require 'py-autopep8)
    (add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook 'py-autopep8-enable-on-save)
```

Comment: I'm curious if you ever got this working with something like `flycheck-define-checker` to call out to `flake8_nb`?